# cygwin to launch a windows path to an executable as a windows user

Tags: cygwin

Is there a way in cygwin to launch a windows path to an executable as a windows user? I am using jEdit and when I launch jedit.exe, it fails to launch. Just kinda sits there. When I launch from windows, works great. Can I use cygutils or something

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here if you can run the exe without cygwin where is the problem? Are you trying to run a script to automatically open it for you?

Comment: I'm sorry for this vague issue. Actually turned out I'm totally stupid - I was launching the command from an ssh terminal without x-windows. It was failing silently - that's why it thru me off. Normally you'd get an error message like "No XDisplay available"

Answer (score 1):

Use `cygstart`. It's essentially equivalent to Windows' Run dialog:

```
cygstart notepad                        # Opens Notepad
cygstart .                              # Opens Explorer in the current directory
echo 'Hi' >file.txt ; cygstart file.txt # Opens file.txt in your default text editor
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did something foolish. I was launching the program from an SSH terminal that didn't have -X windows turned on. Once I went to a cygwin local terminal... the program ran fine.

The ACTUAL problem was the jedit process was hiding the error message "No x display" etc. That is what caused the confusion.